# iOS9.1でiPadキーボードタイプの指定ができない問題について

Tags: ios, objective-c

iPadアプリを開発しております。

テキストフィールドのKeyboardTypeにUIKeyboardTypeASCIICapableでASCIIキーボードを指定しているのですが、iOS9.1のみ以下の画像のように、指定のキーボードタイプとは別のタイプのものが表示されてしまいます。

確認した限りでは、iPad Retina, iPad2, iPad Airで発生しておりました。

左下の地球のマークでキーボードを切り替えようとすると、以下のような「Alternate Keyboard」というダイアログが表示され切り替えが可能になります。

iOS9の場合にも、指定したキーボードタイプを表示するには、どのように指定すればよろしいでしょうか？
現状は、StoryboardとViewController両方で指定をしておりますが、それでも指定のキーボードが表示されないという状況です。

ご教示いただけたらとおもいます。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

スクリーンショットはシミュレーターだと思いますが、「日本語かな」キーボードが現在のキーボードになっています。
おそらくは、これが「日本語ローマ字」キーボード、あるいは「English (US)」キーボードに自動的に切り替わることを期待しているのかと思いますが、そういう動作はしません。

iOSでは（9.1に限らず）ユーザーが「設定」で追加してある複数のキーボードを切り替えられるようになっていますが、keyboardTypeはキーボードそのものを切り替えるのではなく、現在選ばれているキーボードの動作モードを指定するものです。
キーボードそのものを切り替える方法は、ユーザーが地球儀のキーを押す以外にはないと思います。

「日本語かな」キーボードでUIKeyboardTypeASCIICapableを指定した場合は、「ABC」のモードが選択された状態になります。（スクリーンショットもそうなっているので正しく動いていると思います）

その他のキーボードでも、個々のキーボードに応じた適切な動作になります。

iOS 9.1だけがこうなるというのは、iOS 8などの他の試した環境では、現在選ばれているキーボードが「日本語かな」ではなかっただけではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！そのような動作になっているのですね。
理解できました。１点疑問なですが、添付画像でいうところのパスワードのフィールドは、「日本語かな」が設定されてあってもローマ字入力のキーボードが表示されるのですが、これは、Secure Text Entryをオンにしているためでしょうか？

Comment: Secure Text EntryがONの場合はkeyboardTypeと関係なくEnglish (US) に変わるみたいですね。地球儀のキーがありませんから、他のキーボードが選べない状態になると考えていいのかも。他のフィールドに移すと元のキーボードに戻るので切り替えは一時的です。

Comment: なるほどー。詳細に教えていただき、勉強になりました。ありがとうございました!